# Htacces redirect ONLY old home page + index.php to new site in sub-dir; all other pages NOT

Tags: redirect, subdirectory, home-directory

My old site mysite.com is in root. 
I created a new site in a sub-dir mysite.com/2/

When people visit my old site mysite.com (browser looks for the index.php file) OR mysite.com/index.php , I want them to be redirected to my new site mysite.com/2/

All other pages of my old site should NOT redirect, as they are getting lots of traffic, and I created a button to my new site in the header.

Can this be done with a .htaccess rewrite?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, it works, but there's still a delay of 0.5 sec or so, my old homepage pops up, before the refresh, redirect.

Isn't there a smoother way?

Comment: I figured it out. I used php in my old idex.php: header("Location: /2/");

Answer (score 0):

Why bother?  Just use a meta refresh in your home page.

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://mysite/2">
```